# Which film or TV-Show was the first to use a '555-' phone number?

Tags: first-appearance, cinema-history

[image: Toy Story]

<sup>[[Image from Toy Story 3](http://pixar.wikia.com/Andy_Davis#Trivia)]</sup>

Using a fictional **['555-' phone number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/555_(telephone_number))** is [not uncommon](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tl1OAx9u1ok) in American films and television shows.

Which film or television show was the first to use a *'555-'* phone number?

Answer (score 12):

From the [wiki page for 555](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/555_%28telephone_number%29):

The phone companies began encouraging the producers of television shows and movies to use the 555 prefix for fictional telephone numbers, roughly during the 1960s. One of the earliest uses of a 555 number can be seen in *Panic in Year Zero!* (1962), with **555-2106**.

In the 1942 film: *"Eyes in the Night"*, starring Edward Arnold and Donna Reed, the telephone number, "**Rossmore 555**" was referred to. In older television shows from the 1950s or 1960s, "KLondike 5" or "KLamath 5" was used, as at the time the telephone exchanges used letters and numbers in phone numbers.

Depending on your point of view, it could be Eyes in the Night or Panic in Year Zero!, but I will keep digging to see if something else turns up.

Comment: `555` is now a reserved number in phone systems. You can't order a vanity number that starts with `555` anywhere in the world that uses the `###-####` dialing format. Asian countries I think have a different dial format so the rule might not apply.

Comment: I've removed the off-topic conversation about emergency numbers that was unhelpful and had been flagged by several people.

Comment: [This article](http://www.nationmaster.com/encyclopedia/555-telephone-number) says: `...having been used in many films from 1930s, or earlier, onwards.` Unfortunately it doesn't give an example.

Comment: Worth noting, in case it's not obvious, that the system of letters is the same one that still survives on the keypad to this day, so KL5 is dialed as 555.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some I found from searching [Subzin.com](http://www.subzin.com/):

*[Eyes in the Night](http://www.subzin.com/quotes/Eyes+in+the+Night/ROSSMORE+555.)* (1942):

> 00:20:32 ROSSMORE 555.
>   ...
>   00:26:01 I WANT ROSSMORE 555.
>   ...
>   00:26:08 HELLO, ROSSMORE 555?

*[The Second Time Around](http://www.subzin.com/quotes/The+Second+Time+Around/The+number+is+555+-+3485.)* (1961):

> 00:29:59 The number is 555 - 3485.
>   ...
>   00:30:35 That's right. The number is 555 - 3485.

---

KL5 and 555 can be found in a list of (presumably fake) telephone numbers in an advert by the Western Electric telephone company in [*Life* magazine](http://books.google.fi/books?id=l1MEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PP2&dq=555%20%22telephone%20number%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=VjgSUd-IM8Tf4QTAroDQDw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=555%20OR%20KL5&f=false) (15 Dec 1961), with a KL5 number chosen as the main example:

> AreaCode Telephone Number
>   214 RI1-3199
>   311 551-6123
>   918 LU5-0599
>   415 **KL5**-3742
>   502 898-3499
>   516 IV5-9970
>   901 **555**-6255
>   305 355-1199
>   311 579-7892
>   607 RA2-4099
>   914 M08-6098
>   404 **KL5**-7722
>   606 734-9599
>   311 TW5-8242
>   405 CE6 -6690
>   212 **555**-6426
>   713 JA7-4199
>   311 **KL5**-2368
>   315 GR2-2399
>   512 CE4-3499
>   311 FR6-5428

Comment: Wouldn't Rossmore 555 be either 76555 or 767555, depending upon the particular exchange?  In many parts of the US it wasn't necessary to dial seven digits until the late 1970s or early 1980s.

Comment: @supercat: Perhaps the Rossmore one is an earlier version using 555 as a dummy phone number (and Rossmore the area code), before 555 came to be used as a dummy area code.